# How to make a snappy package for EasyCwmp?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I have developed an open-source daemon [EasyCwmp](http://easycwmp.org). EasyCwmp has many dependencies such as libcurl, libubox, libubus, libuci, json, libmicroxml.

I want to generate a snappy package for Ubuntu core for my open-source EasyCwmp. Here are a few of my questions:

1. Should the snappy package contain the pre-built binaries of the
   daemon and the libraries or should it contain only the source code?
2. How to write the .yml file for my case?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use precompiled binaries or generate them during the build. Both is fine.

Having looked at the source of EasyCwmp just briefly, It looks like you could use the `autotools` plugin for this. An example of this in action [can be viewed here](https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/blob/master/dosbox/snapcraft.yaml).

You can use `build-packages` to indicate packages which are required to build, and use `stage-packages` to list .deb packages whose contents you want to bundle in your snap.

Find more information here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/snappy/build-apps